# Yosemite upgrade causing Mail to crash

Tags: macos, mail.app, crash

I upgraded to Yosemite on my 2011-12 iMac, from system 10.6.8.
It worked to a point, but with major problems with the mail - crashing and not working, basically.My Mac tech said it "should work"...but we tried reinstalling 3 times to the same result.
Given Mavericks is no longer available, does anybody have a suggestion other than a clean install of Yosemite? Or is that the only option?

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly happens surrounding the crashes? Does mail.app crash when it opens, halfway through you using it, when a particular email is viewed, etc? Also, when the app does crash, it may help to post a copy of the problem report (in the window that shows after an app crashes) so we may help identify the root cause.

Answer (score -2):

Yosemite mail is horrible, if you have a large inbox it just kills an older machine.  I have a 3ghz mini with 16gb of ram and it STILL crawls.  I am on day 3 of it saying "incoming messages" and slowly the count grows larger and larger. Two apps is all I ask for, Safari and Mail, really people FIX IT.

On my 2009 27" imac I had to restore from time machine back to mavericks.  If you start a restore it will show you what os version was backed up.  Just know it erases your drive so save all of your newer files elsewhere.